# How to fix Angular Service Response to Component - Undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to read a value from API response and use this value from service class, and referring this service variable to all other components, since it is a global value comes from database.

My Component code below,

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dateService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const date = this.dateService.getRunningDay().toDate(); // Here its null
  }
  
}
```

My Service Class as follows,

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  
  constructor(private dateService: DateApiControllerService) {
  }
  
  getRunningDay(): Moment {
      this.dateService.handleGetExecutionDay().subscribe(data => {
        return data;
      });
  }
```

While debugging, before getRunningDay method subscribe comes with data, my component date value executed with null.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Change your return type `Moment` to `any` and check.

Comment: Changed and it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this, I am missing BehaviorSubject's magic. Just wanted to share to someone if get the same issue in future.

My updated component with subscribe the variable in service class, which is BehaviorSubject type,

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  private date: Date;

  constructor(private dateService: DataService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.dateService.date$.subscribe((data) => this.date = data.toDate());
    this.dayMonthYear = this.getDayName(this.date.getDay()) + ' ' + this.getMonthName(this.date.getMonth()) + ' ' + this.date.getDate() + ', ' + this.date.getFullYear();
  }
```

Updated DateService with BehaviorSubject,

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  runningDate: BehaviorSubject<Moment>;

  private date: BehaviorSubject<Moment> = new BehaviorSubject<Moment>(moment());
  date$: Observable<Moment>;

  constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, private dateService: DateApiControllerService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
    this.getRunningDay();
    this.date$ = this.date.asObservable();
  }
  
  
    getRunningDay(): any {
    if (this.runningDate?.value) {
      return this.runningDate.value;
    } else {
      this.dateService.handleGetExecutionDay().subscribe(data => {
        let value = moment(data, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.date.next(value);
        return data;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: This helps, Also it will be good to use service injection at constructor as public instead of private.